# Find the element ID

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python and selenium to try to run through a few Medicare IDs. I want to go to this website and enter a plan ID:

https://www.medicare.gov/find-a-plan/questions/search-by-plan-name-or-plan-id.aspx

I've been able to open the webpage using selenium but I'm unable to enter my plan ID because I am unable to correctly identity the unique ID or name for the plan ID text box. Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has an ID: `ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MCGMainContentPlaceHolder_ToolContentPlaceHolder_PlanFinderContentPlaceHolder_tbPlanID` - how come this doesn't work?

Failing that you should be able to use this [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/input
```

Comment: I've tried both of these and for some reason that I don't understand it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath will find that specific element for you:

```
(//div[@class='textBoxDiv']/input)[2]
```

I tried a few different approaches via CSS and Xpath, but ended up using this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can find your input using text of label `//*[contains(text(),'Plan ID:')]/ancestor::div[2]//input` or you can find label by text and get id of element for this label `//input[@id=(//label[contains(text(),'Plan ID:')]/@for)]`

Comment: I do not mind your down vote but could you please explain the reason? I would really appreciate it if you could point me what wrong is.